# Help defining a wsdl

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I'm trying to use NuSOAP to create a web service, this only has one method that returns true or false, I need help to define the wsdl and the SOAP, there isn't documentation to use SOAP in php and I only have 2 days to finish :S

```
function Transfer($account, $Transactiondate, $amount, $bankID)
{
    //function code
    return $isValidTransfer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has excellent documentation and examples on using SOAP:

http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php

IBM also has SOAP tutorials:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-soa-callsecurephp/index.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-phpws/